# Get all orders based on product id by GraphQL

Tags: api, graphql, shopify, orders

Does anybody know how can I get all orders based on `product id` by GraphQL?
There is no option available to query an argument in [order's](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2021-10/queries/orders) object.
Is there another way to get what I want?

Thank You

Answer (score -1):

You can see the schema. all queries are defined there. You will know how can you apply this query

Comment: Please be more specific when answering questions. The OP has prolly seen the schema, still a supporting example/pinpoint would be helpful